# Can anybody provide authentic quotations regarding Karna-Pishachini?

Tags: scripture, reference-request, sadhana, quote, reference

*Karṇapiśācinī sādhanā* is a well-renowned practice within the occult circles. It is mostly used to obtain material benefits, most notably to obtain knowledge about the past, present & future of somebody. A blog describes the *sādhanā* procedure as follows

> **The *sādhaka* starts the practice on the seventh day of the dark fortnight. During the practice, he shall not take the name of *Hari*, recite a *Vaidika* mantra like *gāyatri*. He shall avoid visiting *tīrtha*s and *kṣhetra*s and speaking to people involved in such practices. The *upavīta* is removed and placed inside a banyan tree. Till *siddhi* is achieved, he shall not wash his hair, face, mouth or excretory and genital organs. Remembering *devatā*s and *pitṛ*s during the *mantrajapa* will act as a thunderbolt on the *piśācinī* and hence also on the *upāsaka*. If the *upāsaka* recites *praṇava* during the period of *sādhanā*, the *japa* done till that point shall go useless. The *sādhaka* shall begin the *japa* at midnight, after getting intoxicated with liquor completely. He shall offer fish [N.B *Vṛhattantrasāra* specifically prescribs burnt fish] *bali* to the *piśācinī* and commence *japa* in a place devoid of *bilva* and *tulasi*. *Japa*, when done with the *mālā* made of bones of a pregnant woman who died at child birth [called *pheṭkāriṇī mālā*] grants *kṣiprasiddhi* of the *piśācinī*.**

Basically, it advises that in order to propitiate *Karṇapiśācinī*, one must abandon basic religious activities like *sandhyāvandanā*, worship & remembrance of *deva*s, *pitṛ-srāddha*, ritual cleanliness & association with holy people. In this regard, this *sādhanā* appears similar to that of *Mañjughoṣa* (a *bodhisattva* propitiated for obtaining eloquent speech & *vāksiddhi* whose *sādhanā* as described in *Vṛhattantrasāra* also involved similar shunning of basic Hindu religious activities).

Although [the blog](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/) which states this, appears to be run by genuinely knowledgeable people, however on principle it is unadvisable to follow blogs that don't quote from authentic sources.

Can anybody, especially @Rickross , provide quotations in Sanskrit from authentic sources, in support of the gory & dreadful nature of *karṇapiśācinī* as quoted above ?

Comment: Idts you can find quotations in scriptures on such esoteric sadhanas that are meant to be kept as a secret so that they do not fall into hands of wrong  and evil people who wish to exploit the knowledge....Only accomplished tantriks have access to such knowledge.